# IE11 - Table cell border issue from 2nd page onwards

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing, internet-explorer-11, sapui5

I have an issue with IE and printing. I have a table that spreads over 5+ pages. On the first page the table borders are fine but from the second page on-wards the second row appears to have an additional thickness. (see images)

This issue only seems to be on printing, on screen it is fine.

It is such a minor thing but I need to find a fix for it, so wondering if anyone has come across this or could recommend a fix.

The company is tied to IE11 so can't use an alternative web browser, although I have tested in Chrome, Firefox and Opera and they all are fine.

[Print page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaIVi.jpg)
[Print page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZTd7.jpg)

Comment: Is the issue still relevant? As you might know already, [UI5 dropped support for IE11 since v1.88](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933). Please consider closing this question if this issue is reproducible in IE11 only.

Answer (score 0):

`@media print {
  border: 1px solid !important;
}`

It may be default IE css for print media. Try fiddling with `@media print`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to revolve around an issue with adjoining borders in IE.  It seems counter intuitive, but this worked as a work-around for me.

```
table {border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: -1px;}
```

Follow the link to see the tracking of the issue.
[Internet Explorer 11 Bug When Printing Table Borders](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/729179/)